# EF - Extract all record of specific type table per hierarchy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, table-per-hierarchy

In my EF context I have a hierarchy of classes, managed with the table per hierarchy approach.

Therefore I have a base abstract class and a bunch of classes that derive from it:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    [Required]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    ...
}

public abstract class ExtendedClass1 : BaseClass
{

    ...

}

public abstract class ExtendedClass2 : BaseClass
{

    ...

}
```

The classes are configured as follows:

```
public class ExtendedClass1Configuration : 
    EntityTypeConfiguration<ExtendedClass1>
{
    ...

    this.Map(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("ExtendedClass1"));
}
```

To access the database I use a repository that derives from a generic repository:

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity: BaseClass
{
    protected DbContext context;

    DbSet<TEntity> GetSet()
    {
        return this.context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        this.GetSet().Add(entity);
    }

    ...
}

public class BaseClassRepository : Repository<BaseClass>, IBaseClassRepository
{

    ...

}
```

I want to add a method to my repository that will extract all the classes of a specific subtype (for example all the records of type `ExtendedClass1`).

I have tried some approaches as follows, without success:

```
public IEnumerable<BaseClass> GetByType(Type type) {
    return context.Set<BaseClass>().OfType<type>();
}
```

This gives me the following compilation error:

> The type or namespace name 'type' could not be found

Another approach I'm trying right now is something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TBaseClass> GetByType() where TBaseClass : BaseClass {
    return context.Set<BaseClass>().OfType<TBaseClass>();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I implement it?

Comment: `OfType<type>();` what the hell is that? (if not a bug)

Comment: Check this line on your GetByType method: return context.Set<BaseClass>().OfType<type>(); It should be return context.Set<BaseClass>().OfType<Type>(); The type name not the variable.

Comment: That line is not compiling, it's only to let you know the various approaches I'm trying @Will

Comment: @KarelTamayo my idea was to pass a specific type to extract, maybe I need to use a generic method passing the type as the generic type, but I'm not getting it right

Comment: It's very distracting.... It's not elegant but you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof(v=vs.110).aspx and/or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx to determine if an instance is of an ancestry you want.  Oh, also, `public IEnumerable<BaseClass> GetByType<T>() { return context.Set<BaseClass>().OfType<T>();}` would be how to implement that method ( if it worked as desired)

Comment: @Will thanks a lot, that was how I wanted to work out the problem and I wasn't able due to my lack of knowledge of generics. I modified the signature of the method as public IEnumerable<BaseClass> GetByType<T>() where T : BaseClass and it's working. Thanks again, you saved my day

Comment: Oh, wasn't sure `OfType<T>` would work like that... I haven't had my coffee yet.  Bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<BaseClass> GetByType(Type type) 
{
    return context.Set<BaseClass>().OfType<type>();
}
```

Isn't correct, use

```
public IEnumerable<BaseClass> GetByType<T>() 
{
    return context.Set<BaseClass>().OfType<T>();
}
```

Typeparams ftw.